# Продвижение сайта

Tags: seo, продвижение, оптимизация

Добрый вечер! 
Недавно создал для себя сайт на тему программирования и разместил его на бесплатном хостинге, хотелось бы донести весь материал до читателей интернета. 
Вопрос такой, как можно оптимизировать сайт, чтобы он появлялся в топе поисковиков? Достаточно ли этого для продвижения сайта, или стоит обратить внимание на другие способы SEO? Поделитесь опытом продвижения сайтов, т.к. я относительно недавно занялся веб-программированием.

Comment: Попробуйте всякие автоматезированные сервисы. Ну типо seopult

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что вопросы по маркетингу и раскрутке не относятся к тематике StackOverflow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Понятие SEO вообще можно разделить на 2 ключевых момента:

1. Можно сделать интересный сайт, но сделать его так, что ни одна поисковая система не будет его воспринимать как нечто целое - здесь SEO выступает как некое руководство относительно того, как верстать сайт под поисковую логику (причем это касается кода, а не внешнего вида). Поисковик это всего лишь робот, который видит то, что соответствует его канонам, прописанным в его логике. А логика основывается на, так сказать, принципах грамотной верстки.
2. Фишка маркетинга и никакого отношения к коду и верстке. Возьмите, к примеру, сайт Студии Лебедева - ежедневно на этот сайт заходят десятки тысяч людей из-за ежедневного т.н. Бизнес-Линча. То есть интересный ежедневный контент (та самая фишка) заставляет людей **ежедневно** посещать сайт, на котором г-ну Лебедеву ничто не мешает параллельно публиковать свои товары, портфолио и проекты, тем самым **неявным** образом ознакамливая посетителей с продукцией и напоминая ежедневно о студии (реклама).

Answer (score 4):

Можно продвигать по низкочастотным запросам.
Домен третьего уровня не сильно на это влияет, но лучше зарегистрировать домен 2 уровня. Цену можно найти подходящую.
Для раскрутки пишите статьи по низкочастотным запросам. Размножайте и публикуйте свои статьи с ссылкой на свой сайт в каталогах с бесплатным размещением.
Ещё лучше активно писать в блогах, форумах, социальных сетях, оставляя ссылки на свой сайт. Если контент у вас интересный, то это привлечёт массу новых посетителей.
Для начала хватит.

Comment: что значит по низкочастотным запросам? В SEO я новичок...

Comment: Низкочастотные запросы — это запросы в поисковой системе, имеющие узкую направленность. Например, "купить чайник bosch".  
Проверить частоту запроса можно [здесь](http://wordstat.yandex.ru/).  
Для запроса "купить чайник bosch" частотность составляет 236 показов в месяц.  
А для среднечастотного запроса "купить чайник" та же величина составляет 24501 показов в месяц.
Высокочастотный запрос "купить квартиру" имеет 2149390 показов в месяц.

Comment: Я кстати купил платный хостинг уже, второго уровня). Думаю разместиться на нем теперь. Спасибо за пояснение по частотности запросов...

Comment: Обращайтесь за помощью если что будет не понятно

Answer (score 3):

Вообще всё зависит от тематики сайта, программирование оно разное бывает, быть в топе поисковиков это смотря как, например есть такие запросы по которым в топ войти довольно таки легко, например у меня был сайт, который по некоторым запросам почти всегда был в пятёрке яндекса и гугла, все зависит от того о чём именно вы будете писать. У яндекса и у гугла есть сервисы анализаторы частоты запросов в месяц, посмотрите как часто ту или иную фразу ищут, посмотрите какие сайты входят в топ, потом анализируйте. А как ещё один способ привлечения трафика на сайт, так соц. сети --- чем не вариант:)

Answer (score 2):

В топе поисковиков по запросу программирование. В вашем случае это невозможно. Нужна мощная команда по продвижению, нудны деньги. 
А у вас сайта на бесплатном хостиинге, да наверно еще и домен второго уровня

Comment: Да, домен второго уровня...

Comment: Скорее всего речь о домене третьего уровня, типа `moysait.ucoz.ru`.
Но ваш вопрос, без обид, из серии `научите как сделать так, чтобы было п**дато`. Ответ на ваш вопрос не уложится ни в комментарий, ни в ответ.
Но тем не менее, следует почитать http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=ru&answer=35291 и https://sites.google.com/site/webmasterhelpforum/ru/stati/rukovodstvo-po-poiskovoj-optimizacii-dla-nacinausih-ot-google, чтобы понимать как все это работает.

Comment: Вообще сайт находится по адресу http://integral.besaba.com/index.php, его вот и хотелось бы оживить как-то...)

Comment: Ну вот я же и говорю, что это третий уровень.